# Is it possible to remove all access to converted leads while still maintaining access to non converted leads?

Tags: permissions, leads

I'm aware of the "View and Edit Converted Leads" permission, which I've already set to false.
The issue is with an integration user and profile.  The service using the integration user counts all lead records.  We only want to count non converted leads.

When I try to access a converted lead in the UI as the integration user, it doesn't display and shows me the converted contact and account.  However, if I query leads as that integration user, I can access all converted leads as well.

Is there a way to truly restrict access to converted lead records, even through API?

Comment: _query leads as that integration user, I can access all converted leads as well_ : how are you running the query? `View and Edit Converted Leads` does work for what you're after.

Comment: does integration user have `View All Data` permission?

Comment: No, user does not have view all data.  For lead object profile has read, edit, and delete. I'm running the query via workbench with the same integration user. View and edit converted leads permission is set to false for this user.